# In Xamarin Android how is AssemblyInfo.cs related to AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**I find it confusing that Xamarin docs examples [suggest](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/#Declare_Permissions) adding permissions to AssemblyInfo.cs like that**:

```
// Need to access the internet for GCM
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.INTERNET")]
```

Why? Permissions are usually defined in AndroidManifest.xml and there's even GUI for that in Xamarin Studio.

**Also seems like AssemblyInfo.cs contains information about title and version**:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyApp")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0")]
```

What does that mean? AndroidManifest.xml also contains title and version info.

How are they related? Seems to be basic knowledge, but didn't found clear explanation about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xamarin just added this way as another way to add permissions but at assembly level, if you do not use it no problem!, you can continue setting the permissions as usual in the AndroidManifest.xml. Reference in this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/mono_for_android_1/mono_for_android_1.9.2/)

Comment: Nice.  
Is it also possible to define version-information for Xamarin Android in AssemblyInfo.cs?  
Would be nice in Xamarin.Forms-Projects where multiple Targets share basically the same version-data.

Answer (score 0):

`AssemblyInfo.cs` generates elements that are inserted into `AndroidManifes.xml`.

More info in the [official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest#application-element)